# Allow user to edit their own data with device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know there's probably solutions to this elsewhere, but I'm looking for help that works specifically in my case because I'm having a lot of trouble translating other solutions into my situation.

I currently have a device set up and the database is seeded so an admin is already created. Everyone else that signs up after that is a user.

There are two tables right now, a user table generated by rails and a cadet table. The cadet table stores information such as `company`, `room number`, `class year` and such.

My question is, how do I allow a user to edit/destroy only the cadet record that they've created? I know it seems like a big question but I've been looking all over and still can't find a reasonable way to implement this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Devise is related to authentication (who you are), you need a solution for authorization (who can do what). My suggestion is to go for CanCan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), which is a gem very widely use together wide Devise.

For your example, and after install the gem via Gemfile+Bundler:

**Initialize the gem for your User model**

```
rails g cancan:ability
```

it will create a file in app/models/ability.rb to define your restrictions

**Define your restrictions, for instance:**

```
class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (this line it to manage users not logged in yet)
    if user
      can :manage, Cadet, user_id: user.id
    end
  end
end
```

That will allow a user just to read, create, edit and destroy Cadets which user_id matches the id for the User.

Take a look at CanCan github page is wery well documented and with lot of examples; it's very simple to set up and works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `before_filter`, something like the following:

```
class CadetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :cadet_belongs_to_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ....
  private

  def cadet_belongs_to_user
    # following will work only on routes with an ID param
    # but there are a few ways you could check if the cadet
    # belongs to the current user
    unless current_user && current_user.cadets.where(id: params[:id]).any?
      flash[:notice] = "You are not authorized to view this page."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```